# Export as Bitmap from inkScape has poor quality

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have drawn something in inkscape and it looks great. I resize the image to the size I want and then export it as a Bitmap. The result has very poor quality, looking like no anti-alias has been applied to it, all edges are jazzy.

All the images are vectors, and I resize them to fit Android screen resolutions. I had the impression that if I use inkscape I will be able to scale and export images and mantain great quality. I attach an image to see the jazzy lines.
[image]

How can I improve this export ?

Comment: Have you tried exporting it in higher resolution? You can increase this in the Export Bitmap dialog under "Bitmap Size".

Comment: D'oh, I should read more carefully; I see now that you said you resized the image. That said, are you sure all the objects in the drawing are vector? Could you post some samples of what you see in Inkscape and what you get in the exported bitmap?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @leppie: It has to do with Android programming.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would actually export it as a SVG open it with Gimp, do additional stuff if required and then save it as a PNG using Gimps save for web function.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this plugins?

It have worked pretty well for me:

http://code.google.com/p/pixelsnap/

The problem about the conversion of vector graphics to pixel based file is explained there.